# How to create Laravel development server without use php artisan

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and i have download voyager admin panel for CRUD operations.
actually my folder structure is

```
testadmin(project name)->vendor->tcg->voyager
```

when i hit `php artisan serve` i got `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` i will get my admin panel

Can i get the same url without using php artisan serve?when i hit `localhost/testadmin/public` i got laravel page and http://localhost/testadmin/public/admin i will get admin page but complete css is missing.how can i access my admin page without artisan serve?please help me.any help would be appreciated

Comment: What server are you using? I know the solution for XAMPP

Comment: @Krishanu am using LAMP server

Comment: Ok so you have apache right?

Comment: @krishanu yep..i have

Comment: When using apache you should note you will need to have a .htaccess file to fix the url's. You can search on laravel pretty urls in google and you'll find it.

Comment: A little better suggestion would be making sure that your development environment is as close as possible to a / the production environment. Therefor I would suggest using something like docker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet) or [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead)

I don't know if you are on Windows env, but I am sure there is an option on Windows too. Artisan serve is for quick checks, I wouldn't use it for development.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `httpd.conf` file in the `/etc/httpd/conf/` folder, if you are on linux.

Uncomment or add the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` so that you can add your own virtual hosts

Then in the file change `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` Add the following lines

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/testadmin/public"
  ServerName YOUR_WEBSITE_NAME
</VirtualHost>
```

then save. now restart the Apache server

```
service httpd restart
```

Hope this solves your problem. this may be a bit complex but i tried something similar on windows and it worked.

Comment: @krishanu-thanks for the reply..but inside etc folder there is no httpd..i am using lamp